# Get tag content in TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

If I have a tag like:

```
<foo>Some content</foo>
```

How can I get the content in a TagHelper?

I can't see anything on `TagHelper` or `TagHelperContext`.

I'm trying to parse the content of a tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is a bit unintuitive, you get the content from the `TagHelperOutput` via the `TagHelperOutput.GetChildContentAsync()` method.

If we have a tag like so:

```html
<my-tag>Some content</my-tag>
```

Then

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var childContext = output.GetChildContentAsync().Result;
    var content = childContext.GetContent();
    // content == "Some content"
}
```

Comment: Override `ProcessAsync` instead of `Process` if you want to use `async` functions.